# ReSharper TypeScript not recognizing implementation

Tags: angularjs, typescript, resharper

I've declared my interface and implemented it but `ReSharper` keeps saying that it was not implemented. Am I doing anything wrong I can't see or is this a `ReSharper` bug?

See image with the warning:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue with DNX projects and ReSharper. Please declare an empty module named 'ng' in one of your files, and everything should work fine afterwards. Will be fixed in the next version of ReSharper.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-451565

Answer (score 0):

It look like the last line has the relevant statement:

Return types are incompatible.

ILoginService.authentificate(...) should return a "ng.IPromise" type.

Comment: I'm returning a promise (see last line of the image). weird is that it works, but I get this red underlyining